# jquery form submission does't work with Ajax.Beginform -ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I Have a form with Ajax.BeginFrom and in that I have button Like this :

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success save" type="submit">save</button>
```

I want befor send data to Action Check somethings , to do this I Use belowe Script :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    (document).on('submit', '#frmpurchase', function (e) {
        var valid = checkpurchaseDetail();
        if (valid == false) {
            e.preventDefault();
          //  return false;
        }
    });

});
```

this code does not work , I always send to Action . 
My form like this :

```
    @using ( Ajax.BeginForm( MVC.Admin.Purchase.Create(),new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    OnSuccess = "addPurchaseseccuess"

},
new {@id="frmpurchase" }
))
{}
```

I seached on google , all of them say this way .

Comment: If you using (cringe) `Ajax.BeginForm()` then you should be using the `OnBegin` option to call a function that returns `true` or `false`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks a lot , sorry about post Title